# SQL Server stored procedure optimal query method?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 5 meta tables that have the same format but depend on 5 other tables. Each Meta table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SiteMetas] 
(
    [SiteMetaId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SiteId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY([SiteId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Sites] ([SiteId]),
    [MetaGroup] [nvarchar] (64) NOT NULL,
    [MetaName] [nvarchar] (128) NOT NULL,
    [MetaType] [char] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- t, i, r, d, s, b
    [MetaBool] [bit] DEFAULT NULL, -- t
    [MetaInteger] [bigint] DEFAULT NULL, -- i
    [MetaReal] [real] DEFAULT NULL, -- r
    [MetaDateTime] [datetime] DEFAULT NULL, -- d
    [MetaString] [nvarchar] (MAX) DEFAULT NULL, -- s
    [MetaBinary] [varbinary] (MAX) DEFAULT NULL, -- b
    [MetaCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()),
    [MetaExpires] [datetime] DEFAULT NULL,
    [MetaUpdated] [datetime] DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SiteMetaId] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([SiteId] ASC, [MetaGroup] ASC, [MetaName] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
);
```

This is for `Site` but there's 4 more. Like `Users`, ...

And I want to read the `Binary` meta value from `Site`. So wrote this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSiteMetaBinary]
  @SiteId AS bigint,
  @Group AS nvarchar(64),
  @Name AS nvarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 [MetaBinary] 
    FROM [dbo].[SiteMetas]
    WHERE [SiteId] = @SiteId
      AND [MetaGroup] = @Group 
      AND [MetaName] = @Name 
      AND [MetaType] = 'b';
END;
```

This stored procedure has duplicates for `User` too... and the rest of the tables. That just replaces `Site` with `User` in its body.

But thinking that I have too many of these I wrote this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMeta]
  @Set AS nvarchar(64),
  @Id AS bigint,
  @Group AS nvarchar(64),
  @Name AS nvarchar(128),
  @Type AS nvarchar(16)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Flag nchar(1);
    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @Flag = CASE @Type
        WHEN 'Bool' THEN 't'
        WHEN 'Integer' THEN 'i'
        WHEN 'Real' THEN 'r'
        WHEN 'DateTime' THEN 'd'
        WHEN 'String' THEN 's'
        WHEN 'Binary' THEN 'b'
        ELSE NULL
    END;

    SET @Sql = N'SELECT TOP 1 [Meta' + @Type + N'] FROM [dbo].[' + @Set + N'Metas]' +
        N'WHERE [' + @Set + N'Id] = @Id AND [MetaGroup] = @Group AND [MetaName] = @Name AND [MetaType] = @Flag;';

    -- SELECT @Sql; -- DEBUG

    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql,
        N' @Id AS bigint, @Group AS nvarchar(64), @Name AS nvarchar(128), @Flag AS nchar(1)',
        @Id, @Group, @Name, @Flag
        ;
END;
```

which is a general use stored procedure to read any data typed stored in a column based on input arguments. I use it like this `[dbo].[GetMeta] 'Site', 1, 'group', 'name', 'Binary'` the difference being that the actual query is dynamically generated so it's not known before hand by SQL Server like the first specialized variant.

Which of the two choices is better from a performance point of view and friendlier to SQL Server's internals? A dedicated one for each table and column data type of a general one that internally builds a query based on fed arguments.

I can use either. I like the last as it does not pollute my stored procedure space. :) The first one is more clear and SQL Server might be able to optimize it better. Not sure...

PS: I'm quite new to SQL Server

Comment: If it's just 5 tables I would create separate procedures, because this dynamic is harder to understand and it's now open for sql injection.

Comment: @JamesZ :) **I sanitize the data in C#.** The only free strings are `@Group` and `@Name` which I pass as arguments to the second `SProc` so I assume it's escaped internally. The rest don't get any wiggle room and are pre-verified.

Answer (score 1):

Static procedures are usually faster because the SQL engine can cache the compiled SP's execution plan.

However, unless this SP will be called a lot or is time-critical, it probably isn't worth worrying about it because the time savings of only having to maintain one SP will make up for the very small amount of time difference spent waiting for the SP to finish.

Comment: dynamic sql gets cached just the same as a procedure. Converting to a procedure does not automatically make it go faster.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not sure what that has to do with what I said.  He is referring to dynamic sql inside a procedure vs static sql inside a procedure.  The dynamic will have to be re-interpreted every time the SP is run.

Comment: The plan is cached either way. The dynamic sql runs in its own context so it is a separate execution from the procedure. The plan would still be cached and the dynamic sql isn't re-interpreted.

Comment: @SeanLange It has to be reinterpreted if it changes, that's what makes it dynamic.  You are right, the run will be cached, but when the query changes, the old cache is worthless, thus making the run time longer because it has to redo the whole process from scratch.  The OP's question states that the SP will be changing for each table he runs it against.  That would mean that caching becomes inconsistent more often.